# Bash $PS1 Trouble (ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ps1

So I have a script in my `.bashrc` for customizing my prompt (see below).

```
function git_unpushed {
    brinfo=$(git branch -v)
    if [[ $brinfo =~ ("[ahead "([[:digit:]]*)]) ]]
    then
        echo "Not Pushed: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
}

function git_untracked {
    untracked=$(git clean --dry-run | wc -l)
    if [ $untracked -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "Untracked: "$untracked
    fi
}

export PS1="\
$(
    # last_result=$?
    uid="$(id -u)"
    host="\[\e[97m\]\H"
    path="\[\e[94m\]\w"
    
    # If root
    if [ "$uid" = "0" ];
    then
        user="\[\e[95m\]\u"
        symbol="\[\e[97m\]#"
    else
        # If not root
        user="\[\e[96m\]\u"
        symbol="\[\e[97m\]\$"
    fi
    
    # If Git Repo
    if [ -d './.git' ];
    then
        unpushed=$(git_unpushed)
        untracked=$(git_untracked)
        branch=$(__git_ps1)
        status=$(git diff --shortstat)
        second_line="hi"
    else
        second_line=$path
    fi
    
    echo "\[\e[1m\]$user@$host\n$second_line\n$symbol: \[\e[0m\]"
)"
```

**My Question:** Why does the path not get replaced whenever I `cd` to a git repo? (it does if I start a bash prompt within the repo"

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

---

## Update:

After lot of work getting it just right, he is my result: [Custom $PS1](http://pastebin.com/U7PGwc6v)

Thanks everyone who helped out!

Comment: `\$` is `$` for non-root and `#` for UID 0. So that bit of that script is pointless.

Comment: Print out the value of `$PS1` after it has been set and see what you get. Hint: You won't get that script back.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, but that is not something that is automatically put in, and I am using the same script for root (UID of 0) and non-root users. Therefore, it is not pointless.

Comment: Single quote the setting of `PS1` instead of double quoting it and it should work fine.

Comment: I'm confused. You are manually duplicating what `\$` when used in `PS1` does for you. The literal string `\$` in `PS1` will expand to `$` or `#` correctly for the current user. What do you think you are doing that that doesn't?

Comment: @EtanReisner For whatever reason, on my system, it's not changing when I am root, so I have to change it manually.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't this same "runs only once" problem? Try setting a simple `PS1="\$ "' and then changing users (and checking/setting PS1 to make sure it still has `\$` in it).

Comment: still no good. idk why it's doing this, but's not really a big deal if it is a simple as adding 1 var

Comment: If you simply run `PS1='\$ '` at both a root and non-root shell do you get the correct `$` and `#` results? If you set that in the respective shell init files does it still work?

Comment: I see what I did now, I forgot about the diff between double & single quotes. In this case `"\$"` is interpreted as literal `$` whereas `'\$'` would be `\$`.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it (above and beyond the run-one problem of this issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit:

As **@EtanReisner** points out, your code should work as intended for all users by enclosing your command substitution in single quotes.

```
    export PS1='\
    $(
        # last_result=$?
        uid="$(id -u)"
        host="\[\e[97m\]\H"
        path="\[\e[94m\]\w"

        # If root
        if [ "$uid" = "0" ];
        then
            user="\[\e[95m\]\u"
            symbol="\[\e[97m\]#"
        else
            # If not root
            user="\[\e[96m\]\u"
            symbol="\[\e[97m\]\$"
        fi

        # If Git Repo
        if [ -d "./.git" ];
        then
            unpushed=$(git_unpushed)
            untracked=$(git_untracked)
            branch=$(__git_ps1)
            status=$(git diff --shortstat)
            second_line="hi"
        else
            second_line=$path
        fi

        echo "\[\e[1m\]$user@$host\n$second_line\n$symbol: \[\e[0m\]"
    )'
```

### Old Answer:

This is because what you want to happen is only running every time your ~/.bashrc gets sourced. To get it to run after every command you execute, you can create a function and set the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to that function.

Try this:

```
new_ps1 (){
    export PS1="\
    $(
        # last_result=$?
        uid="$(id -u)"
        host="\[\e[97m\]\H"
        path="\[\e[94m\]\w"

        # If root
        if [ "$uid" = "0" ];
        then
            user="\[\e[95m\]\u"
            symbol="\[\e[97m\]#"
        else
            # If not root
            user="\[\e[96m\]\u"
            symbol="\[\e[97m\]\$"
        fi

        # If Git Repo
        if [ -d './.git' ];
        then
            unpushed=$(git_unpushed)
            untracked=$(git_untracked)
            branch=$(__git_ps1)
            status=$(git diff --shortstat)
            second_line="hi"
        else
            second_line=$path
        fi

        echo "\[\e[1m\]$user@$host\n$second_line\n$symbol: \[\e[0m\]"
    )"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="new_ps1"
```

Comment: `PS1` is evaluated before each prompt is displayed. There's no reason to need to go through `PROMPT_COMMAND` for this. Though you are correct (I think accidentally) that the `PS1` in this case was only being evaluated once.

Comment: You're right, @EtanReisner.  This is is actually working for me as the OP posted it, and I think using `PROMPT_COMMAND` here might only cause problems.  @NickJ I would delete the answer if it wasn't already accepted :\

Comment: Correct, this certainly looks like it will work it just isn't necessary.

Comment: @EtanReisner I stole your suggestion for my edit as it is the right approach, hope you don't mind.  I'd gladly give you the accepted answer if I could.